# Compile program to run with older version of Excel

Tags: c#, excel

Currently i am making an program that exports data to excel.
My computer is runing windows 7 and office 2013, but the 
program should be able to run on older pcs whit windows XP
and office 2010. When i run the app on xp it returns an error
that .

I found out that i should compile for an older version of 
office. I tried to dowload o2010pia installer but after trying
to install the program it closes after the load bar movin 10% or so.

this is my refference

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            string rangeborder = (4 + student.GetLength(0)).ToString();

            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B4", "E" + rangeborder).Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B4", "E" + rangeborder).Borders.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Black);
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B4", "E" + rangeborder).Borders.Weight = 3d;
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B4", "E" + rangeborder).Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;

            Excel.Range er = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C:D", System.Type.Missing);

            er.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 25;

            xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 6]].Merge();

            xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 2] = " ";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 3] = "a";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 4] = "b";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 5] = "c";

            for (int x = 0; x < student.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[x + 5, 2] = x;


            }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(path + "abc" + printDatum() + "_"+ ".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use a third-party library like [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/), which wraps  the Office-Communication so you don't have to bother about the version.

There is already a [SO Article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30047246/1389444) with an answer which will help you.

> Features provided by NetOffice
>
> - Office integration without version limitations
> - All features of the Office versions 2000, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013 are included
> - Syntactically and semantically identical to the Microsoft Interop Assemblies
> - No training if you already know the Office object model, use your existing PIA code
> - Usable with .NET version 2.0 or higher
> - No dependencies, no interop assemblies, no need for VSTO

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered that problem, I figured that only compiling on a system with such an old office was the solution.

The 2010 PIA package helps you when its up to the deployment of your app, but sadly you need to compile it on a machine having office 2010.

I personally worked on the app using my computer with office 2013. When it came to the deployment, I used a virtual machine having office 2010 to compile the app.

Comment: the virutal PC would be an elegant solution, but that would mean that i need to get an extra copy of office 2010. It sthere a way to get a legit office or reader 2010 that would allow compailing.

Comment: You should be able to use the test-version, since you don't need to start the software. If you'd ask Microsoft, they'd probably tell you that you need to own the software you want do develop for... But since you don't use that installation for development, just for compiling, it won't need to be activated (I think).

Comment: Interesting. How about windows licencing for virutal ? Do i nead an extra licence or can i user my current ?

Comment: From the licensing point: No, you probably can't use your existing (due to agreement stuff). Here, you might use a not activated copy, as well. The virtual machine won't need an internet-connection. And there are alternatives, like the [XP-Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/de-de/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7) when you have Windows 7 Pro/Ent/Ult.

Comment: Or simply use sth like NetOffice as this [SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047112/multiple-versions-of-office-primary-interop-assemblies-in-net-project) states.